# How to access database in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the default asp.net application, I want to access the data of other users. In my database table ASPNETUSERS I have columns such as Id, Email, Password, Gender etc. Now I want to be able to search for a particular Id and get that user's entire details like his/her Email, Password, Gender etc. So how do I do that?

1. Do I use raw SQL? If so how? (someone on SO mentioned this as a bad idea)
2. Do I use models or something else? if so how?

This is my ASPNETUSERS Table info. And this is my action in a controller. I want to be able to get an user called "stackoverflow@gmail.com" and send all his details(whatever are there in my table) to the view.

[image]

```
 private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
 public ActionResult Index(string id = "")
        {
            //db.someCommand or something to let me get stuff about 
            //stackoverflow@gmail.com. Could it be db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand ?

            return View("Send All details about my stackoverflow user");
        }
```

Edit: This is what I tried before. I tried to use raw sql and convert it to a string(for testing) and write it to a file on desktop. That way I thought I would at least know that the data in my database is getting passed back to me correctly before I pass it to my view.

This was my line of code that I added just before my action returned.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\log.txt", db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select * from dbo.AspNetUsers").ToString());
```

I did not get any errors doing so, but I expected my data from the image above to be posted into my file called log.txt on desktop. But I opened log.txt file only to find that "-1" was posted in there.

Comment: I tried Database.SqlExecuteCommand and tried to convert it to a string and write it to a file, but in my file "-1" got added and nothing else.

Comment: Shows us some code, give us something to work with.

Comment: This is what I did. `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\log.txt", db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select * from dbo.AspNetUsers").ToString());`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Also: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Yes I have elaborated. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: you mean you dont know how to get connection from code behind to DB?

Comment: What DB you've using?

Comment: @reds I don't quite understand what you are saying as I am completely new to ASP.NET. But if I am right, there is no code behind in modern MVC right? Code Behind was a word used in .aspx/web forms only right? It is obsolete(at least from what I heard from Microsoft's Virtual Academy Course) right? I am using SQLServer, the one that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: I mean what Database you are using?MYSQL,SQL,POSTGRES,ORACLE etc...

Comment: Oh ok. It's SQLServer.

Comment: Oh the irony. The question was put on hold as it was too broad? No problem because the moderators who looked at this question didn't read it properly. Besides I got the perfect answer already, which I was not able to find anywhere on SO. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the users from your database, use `linq` with your ApplicationDBContext object

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
//Manipulate the Where clause to get the conditions you want
IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> users = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == "stack@overflow.com");
```

This works with the out of the box ASP.NET individual authentication model (which looks like what you have)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for.